# How to allow anonymous profile editing on Wordpress

Tags: civimember

We have a Wordpress site with CiviCRM. Only a few administrative users are allowed to login. We need to be able to let anonymous users modify their contact information. Below is info I copied from the wiki. Is it possible to do this with a Wordpress installation? Is the information current? How would the link be created in the email? The scenario is that when a user renews their membership using the online form, they get a confirmation email. The email must have the appropriate link to the secure form used to edit the contact info.

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Linking+Profiles

> Allow Anonymous (not-logged-in) Users to Edit Their Profile
>   A great feature is to "invite" your non-logged in users the ability to view and edit their contact info via a profile using CiviMail. To do this, insert the following link with appropriate tokens as shown into a CiviMail message:
>   http:///civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
>   ... where N is the ID of the Profile you want them to use for editing. The contact checksum token generates a special link that gives a user access to edit their information in that profile for 7 days from the day you send them the mailing.

Answer (score 1):

the above should all be fine though that looks like a Drupal link. So if you want people to get a confirmation email when they pay for membership that contains a checksum link to a profile then I would suggest using a Scheduled Reminder triggered off a change of Membership status, and include

WordPress: http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}

where N is the id of the Profile you have set up with the fields of 'contact related' data you want them to edit.

Check your links [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens)